# My SQL Error na session e na query

Tags: php

Tenho uma classe onde eu uso pra poder pegar o nome de usuário, e dentro dela tenho o método:

```
public function getfName() {
        $Session = $_SESSION[$this->Prefix . 'username'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_DBPREFIX . "$this->Table WHERE name = $Session";

        try {
            $stmt = Conn::dbPrepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
                $data = $row[1];
                print $data;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Só que quando coloco a variável $Session na minha query obtenho esse erro:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TheNight' in 'where clause'`

Eu procurei aqui no Stack e em outros sites e encontrei um tópico porém não me ajudou, então resolvi abri este!

Comment: Tente colocar assim: `name='$Session'` entre aspas simples

Comment: @DiegoMachado você quase conseguiu rsrs, o erro sumiu mais não apareceu o que eu queria, quero pegar meu nome la na DB e imprimir na tela...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude a seguinte linha:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
```

Para:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Veja se vai funcionar.

Editado:

Cara, como não sei como está sua conexão, vou postar um exemplo funcionando completo:

```
$name = 'nome';

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', "user", "pass");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE name = ' . $conn->quote($name));

    $row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo $row['name'];

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Quando ele retorna `false` é porque ocorreu algum erro.
Faça a adaptação para seu código e teste.

Comment: Não, não mudou! http://i.imgur.com/fuCT0a3.png era pra aparecer Guilherme ali aonde tá marcado em vermelho

Comment: Só para confirmar, eu tinha colocado inicialmente assim: `PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC` com um espaço depois dos dois pontos, depois corrigi. Verifica se o seu ta com esse espaço, caso tiver, tire-o e teste, senão, me fale.

Comment: Opa, ta sem espaço, uma observação quando dou um `var_dump($data)` me retorna `boolean false`.

Comment: Editei o código, veja se funciona.

Comment: mesma coisa, meu Deus que coisa chata esse negócio rsrs, ta tenso :/

Comment: Muito estranho isso, acabei de testar antes de postar e funcionou. Você já usou PDO antes? Ele está habilitado? Se você nunca usou talvez precise habilita-lo.

Comment: Sim tá habilitado, pois já usei antes... será que não estou fazendo errado? Pois segui todos os passos que você me passou, estou tentado apenas imprimir meu nome que esta la na `DB` :/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24334/discussion-between-diego-machado-and-guilherme-alves).

Comment: me ajudou repare na query: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_DBPREFIX . "$this->Table WHERE username = '$Session'";` agora compare com a outra :D pronto Valeu Diego!